# Generated style not present in any source file or in db

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4.4

I'm building an ecommerce with Magento.
For what concerns the "As low as" label, present in configurable products when you haven't chosen all the attributes (it shows "As low as" followed by the minimum price) I don't see it in my browser.

If I inspect the code I see it is there and it has the inline css `display:inline` when not all the attributes are selected and `display:none` when all the attributes are selected and the price of the choosen configuration is shown. And that would be the expected behavior, except there is this code:

```
.product-info-main .price-box .price-label,
.product-options-bottom .price-box .price-label {
  display: none !important;
}
```

in a static css file inside `pub/static/version**********/_cache/merged/`, so the label is never shown.

The selector that affects the label I want to see is `.product-info-main .price-box .price-label`

So I made a search into every single Magento file to find the source file that generates that static code.
I looked into every file (not only css or less) for the string `.product-info-main .price-box .price-label` or even for `.product-info-main` but i find it only in static files in `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static` or in `pub/static`.

I also tried to look for that in the db but I didn't find it.

Does anybody have an Idea of where I could find the css original code that generates that static code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems this code does not exist in the Magento core code. I think it is located in a custom module/theme. Can you search for ".price-label", "**display:none** !important" and "display: none !important"?